# posting form data with Axios to .NET API

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, axios

I'm using React and Axios to post formData to an internal .NET API.

The API is expecting data like this:

```
    [HttpPost("upload")]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> PostMulti(Int64 parentId, ICollection<IFormFile> fileData)
    {
        foreach (var file in fileData) {
            await SaveFile(file, parent);
        }

        return Created("", Map(Repository.Get(parentId)));
    }
```

When I step through the debugger, the count for "fileData" is always 0.

Here is how I'm sending it using Axios:

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', this.state.file);

    console.log("this.state.file = ", this.state.file);
    console.log("formData = ", formData);

    axios({
        url: `/api/gameMethods/playerStates/${this.props.playerId}/files/upload`,
        method: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
       .then((response) => {
            //handle success
            console.log('response -- then: ', response);
            this.setState({
                file: this.state.file
            });
        })
        .catch((response) => {
            //handle error
            console.log('response -- catch: ', response);
        });
```

I use console.log for debugging.  It shows me the file object when I write it out(name, size, etc).

It also fires in the ".then" handler of the method and shows this:

> "response -- then: data: Array(0), status: 201, statusText: "Created"
>   "

So, I have no idea why it's not sending anything to the API and I don't really know what's happening or how to fix this problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should post array of the `formData`

```
const filesToSubmit = []
filesToSubmit.push((new FormData()).append('image', this.state.file))
```

and while posting the data the property name should be `formData`

```
axios({
    url: `/api/gameMethods/playerStates/${this.props.playerId}/files/upload`,
    method: 'POST',
    data: {formData : filesToSubmit},
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
})
```

*If there is an issue with constructing an array you need to add `IFormFile` properties to the array*

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work.  It seems to be working on the front end side, but when it gets passed to the API, it is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

So I had exactly the same issue, whereby no matter which way I twisted the `FormData` object and regardless of the headers I sent, I couldn't get .NET to accept the submission.

From the Node.js side, it was difficult to actually inspect the HTTP call issued by Axios - meaning I couldn't see what I was actually POSTing.

So I moved the POST to the UI for some debugging, and found that the `FormData` payload was not being passed as I was expecting, so it was proper that .NET was rejecting.

I ended up using the configuration below, and the POSTs began going through.  Again, in my case, I thought I needed `FormData`, but the below was simple enough:

```
axios({
    url: myUrl,
    method: 'POST',
    data: `email=${myEmail}`,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    })
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

**Update**: Not sure how encoded data will work, but since it'll be passed as a string, it's worth a shot!

```
const myUploadedImage = "data:image/png;name=colors.png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA5gAAAEECAIAAADCkQz7AAAGGUlEQVR4nO3YIY/IcRzHcWd4AjZJkZQr2I1dIJlyRU5ErkJggg=="
```

Comment: I can see how this could work for a string(myEmail) but I'm not sure it would work in my issue because I'm trying to pass an uploaded image to the API.

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Good point, I updated the answer - since it'll be base64 encoded, which is a string, it's worth giving it a shot, but who knows. I was strictly dealing with string form fields.